# how to resume my video wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a video control to play my video but I can't resume my video ; won't you please help me; with media element ;
thank you very much

```
    void BrowseClick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openDlg = new OpenFileDialog();
        openDlg.InitialDirectory = @"c:\";
        openDlg.ShowDialog();
        MediaPathTextBox.Text = openDlg.FileName;
    }

    void PlayClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (MediaPathTextBox.Text.Length <= 0)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Enter a valid media file");
            return;
        }
        VideoControl.Source = new Uri(MediaPathTextBox.Text);
        VideoControl.Play();
    }
    void PauseClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        VideoControl.Pause();
    }
    void StopClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        VideoControl.Stop();
    }
}
```

//////////////////////////////////////
and my xaml code is here

```
<TextBox Height="20" Margin="10,7,134,0" Name="MediaPathTextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top"  ></TextBox>
<Button Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,6,14,0" Name="BrowseButton" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="94" Click="BrowseClick">
    Browse Media
</Button>
<MediaElement Canvas.Left="20" Canvas.Top ="40" 
        Name="VideoControl" LoadedBehavior="Manual" UnloadedBehavior="Stop" >
  </MediaElement>

<Button Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="15,0,0,13" 
        Name="PlayButton" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75" 
        Click="PlayClick">
  Play</Button>
<Button Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="103,0,0,13" 
        Name="PauseButton" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75" 
        Click="PauseClick">
  Pause</Button>
<Button Height="23" Margin="191,0,186,13" Name="StopButton" 
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  Click="StopClick">
  Stop</Button>
```

Comment: what do you use for video control?

Comment: -1 How are we supposed to know anything about *your* `VideoControl`?

Comment: Is "Pause" not working, or "Stop"? What steps do you take?

Comment: both of them work but how can I resume it and not starting from beginning of the video

Comment: Well, your "Play" button likely reloads the video (by resetting the URI) sounds like you need some new logic to load or just play a video. Have you tried seperating that out?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET  thanks alot; my problem was soleved ;

Comment: Glad you got it fixed! Note for a comment to appear in my inbox, preface my name with the @ symbol

Answer (score 1):

just use video control.play () under resume button;

```
   void resumeClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // VideoControl.Stop();
        VideoControl.Play();
    }
```